# Grails plugin not detecting the dependencies of another plugin it uses

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, dependency-management

I am using grails 2.3.7, in windows.

I want to develop a grails-plugin **schedulePlugin**  which should work with another grails plugin **dbPlugin**

My Build config for schedulePlugin

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver="ivy"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    legacyResolve true // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
    repositories {        

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()        
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()

        mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
    dependencies {       

    }

    plugins {

        runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.10'

        build(        
             ":tomcat:7.0.50.1",
              ":release:2.2.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }

        //Own           
        compile ":grails-dbPlugin:2.0-A6"
    }
```

My Build config for dbPlugin

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()




        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/" //Added this repo to resolve plugin dependencies for hibernate, joda, zk & quartz.
        mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
    dependencies { 

    }

    plugins {  


    compile ":audit-logging:1.0.1"

    compile ":database-migration:1.3.8"

    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.10"   

    build(":release:3.0.1"
          ,":rest-client-builder:1.0.3"
          ,":tomcat:7.0.50.1") {
      export = false
    }    

  }
}
```

when i compile schedulePlugin, it give me compilation error

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\projects\scheduler\target\work\plugins\dbPlugin-2.0-A6\grails-app\migrations\init-changelog.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class liquibase.statement.core.
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import liquibase.statement.core.InsertStatement
```

I can resolve the error if i add the **compile ":database-migration:1.3.8"** to BuildConfig of schedulePlugin

But shouldnt it be automatically inherit the dependencies of dbPlugin . Can some one assist with how the dependency should be resolved in this case

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You declare formal plugin dependencies in the plugin descriptor file. For example, if my plugin was named arkDashboard, then the descriptor file is ArkDashboardGrailsPlugin.groovy in the root of my plugin project. Here is an example of a dependency declaration for another plugin named "arkCore":

```
// Plugins that we are dependent on
def dependsOn = [
    "arkCore": "1.2.2 > *"
]
```

The descriptor file should already be in your plugin project (created by Grails) with this section already stubbed out. You just need to fill it in. See the Plugins section of the manual for details on plugin dependency resolution.

It is a little confusing because you can "fix" the dependencies with explicit rules in the BuildConfig.groovy file, but your instincts are correct and you should leave it to dependency resolution if you can. It makes the code less brittle.

Comment: Modified the descriptor file . Still not working . Getting the same error

Comment: I need to see your SchedulePluginGrailsPlugin.groovy file (assuming the actual name of your plugin is "schedulePlugin".  Regardless, I need to see the descriptor file to see what is wrong.

Comment: Just to make it clear i modified the descriptor file of dbPlugin. SchedulePlugin -> DbPlugin -> databasemigration plugin. Schedule Plugin cant get databasemigration plugin unless i put it in BUildConfig of Schedule Plugin.                                class DBPluginGrailsPlugin {
    // the plugin version
    def version = "2.0-A6"
    // the version or versions of Grails the plugin is designed for
    def grailsVersion = "2.0.0 > *"
    // the other plugins this plugin depends on
    def dependsOn = [
          "database-migration": "1.3.8 > *"
          ]

Comment: That is pretty much how I understood it. The dependsOn definitions should work for you. I have many examples of chained depende

Comment: That is pretty much how I understood it. The dependsOn definitions should work for you. I have many examples of chained dependencies in my complicated plugin architecture. Note that prior to 2.3, dependency support wasn't that great. Try running the "grails dependency-report" command to dump the dependency map that grails calculates in your main project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you run into the same problem as I did. It looks to me like the problem originates from the fact that your app uses the "ivy" resolver whereas the plugin uses the "maven" resolver.

See also: [Using Grails plugins that use "maven" dependency resolver in a Grails app that uses "ivy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218400/using-grails-plugins-that-use-maven-dependency-resolver-in-a-grails-app-that-u)

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation plugin has a runtime dependency in its BuildConfig.groovy

```
runtime 'com.javadocmd:simplelatlng:1.0.0'
```

You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/sebastienblanc/geolocation/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy)

Now simply  add this in your dependencies clause of your app and it will work.