# Using Grails plugins that use "maven" dependency resolver in a Grails app that uses "ivy"

Tags: java, maven, grails, groovy

in an application I have to use the legacy "ivy" dependency resolver together with Grails 2.2.1. I noticed that dependencies from plugins that have been released using "maven" as the dependency resolver are not picked up in my application. It works if I manually add those dependencies to the app itself. So in other words transitive dependencies of the plugins are not picked up.

After having a look at the content of the installed Grails plugins that there isn't any longer a "dependencies.groovy" file bundled when the dependency resolver is configured as "maven". I guess that is the reason why the Ivy resolver of the app don't pick up the transitive dependencies.

Is there a way to enable the Ivy resolver to pickup transitive dependencies from plugins that use the maven resolver?

Any ideas much appreciated.

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: 'More or less' it seems to be doable. Don't know the reason but even if `mavenCentral()` is declared I can't find any `pom.xml`. Instead only `ivy.xml` files are found.